# How to set minOccurs="0" or nillable="true" to wsdl element by using of python module with name "pysimplesoap"

Tags: java, python, wsdl, pysimplesoap

We use pysimplesoap module for writting of services. Clients were written on Java. There are problems with convertation of xml datatype to java. I suppose, we need to set minOccurs="0" or nillable="true" to wsdl elements. But in pysimplesoap file with name [server.py](https://code.google.com/p/pysimplesoap/source/browse/pysimplesoap/server.py) there is such conversion for Arrays only. Is it possible to make it without kludges and how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Configure the dispatcher as usual:

```
dispatcher.register_function('test_function', test,
returns={'Success': str}, 
args={'wanted': str,'optional': str,'another_optional':str })
```

When defining your method, mark optional fields with defaults:

```
def test_request(wanted, optional=None, another_optional="Optional"):
return "Success"
```

Comment: We found, that it's possible to set minOccurs for Arrays only. But anyway, the question was closed.